# XSLT, I'm studying with my own XSLT example, but it doesn't work as I expected

Tags: xslt

First, my code is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mpml>
   <problem>
      <context>
         <p>두 다항식 $A=x^2 - xy + 2y^2$, $B=3x^2 + 2xy - y^2$에 대하여 $A-B$를 계산한 식이 $ax^2 +bxy + cy^2$일 때, 상수 $a+b+c$의 값은?</p>
      </context>
      <answerlist>
         <i>-4</i>
         <i>-2</i>
         <i>0</i>
         <i>2</i>
         <i>4</i>
      </answerlist>
   </problem>

   <problem>
      <context>
         <p>연립방정식 $\begin{cases} x+y+z=30 \\ 2x+3y+4z=93 \\ y=z+3 \end{cases}$의 해를 $x=a$, $y=b$, $z=c$라 할 때, $a-2b+3c$의 값은? (단, $a$, $b$, $c$는 실수.)</p>
      </context>
      <answerlist>
         <i>7</i>
         <i>9</i>
         <i>11</i>
         <i>13</i>
         <i>15</i>
      </answerlist>
   </problem>
</mpml>
```

and it's xsl code is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="/">
   <h2> Testing.. </h2>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="problem">
      <div class="problem">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="context"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="answerlist"/>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="context">
      <div class="context">

      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="answerlist">
      <div class="answerlist">
         test answerlist
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

In XSLT Tryit editor (thanks to w3school), above XSLT work as I expected. However when I tried this in my server, there is an 'extra content at the end of the document.' error and nothings shown except very first template.

Comment: We don't know what the expected output is. In any case, the posted code does not produce any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your XSLT does not produce well-formed XML in output: in the template `<xsl:template match="/">`, you should wrap content within a single root tag.

E.g.:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <body>
       <h2> Testing.. </h2>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </body>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is no requirement for an XSLT stylesheet to produce a well-formed XML document. If this is the cause of the error, then the error is not thrown by the XSLT processor (or at least it shouldn't be).